# Unable to enroll test user in Garden FI

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I just signed up for a developer account today and created a test user. When trying to enroll the test user in Garden FI, I get the following error message: Oops, something went wrong on our end. Please try again.

Inspecting the network traffic, I'm getting a 400 Bad Request.

POST https://digital.garden-fi.com/a/consumer/api/v0/enrollment/lookup

Response (redacted):

```json
{
    "type": "json",
    "messages": [
        "Invalid message body: Could not decode JSON: {\n  \"identifier\" : \"xxxxxxxxx\",\n  \"institutionId\" : \"xxxxxxx\",\n  \"accountNumber\" : \"xxxxxx\",\n  \"phone\" : \"xxxxx\",\n  \"email\" : \"xxxxxx\",\n  \"deviceId\" : \"online-xxxxxx\",\n  \"deviceInfo\" : {\n    \"appVersion\" : \"2.1748.0\",\n    \"os\" : \"Windows\",\n    \"osVersion\" : \"10.0.0\",\n    \"browser\" : \"Microsoft Edge\",\n    \"browserVersion\" : \"120.0.2210.144\",\n    \"browserEngine\" : \"Blink\",\n    \"browserEngineVersion\" : \"120.0.2210.144\"\n  }\n}"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Has anyone else encountered this problem today, January 25th, 2024? If so, that would be useful to know to understand if this is an isolated problem or a broader issue.

Comment: In the meantime, we'll check with Engineering on this topic.

Comment: what was the day/time when you encountered the error? That would be helpful to know as well.

Comment: Either way, we can get your developer account unstuck if you use the contact form from the "Interested in building together? Let's talk" button on the JackHenry.Dev homepage. The "I have technical questions about the Digital Toolkit" form is something you can use to privately share 1) the email address used for the _Sign in with Google_ button as well as 2) the `/me` network call response body from the developer dashboard.

Comment: It was yesterday around 2 PM PST. It's still occurring at this time though.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. Current hypothesis is that you were unlucky enough to register when the system encountered a temporary glitch. We've received your info via the contact form and are working with Engineering to see about resetting your developer account. We'll let you know when you can try again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Engineering has reset your developer account. Please try again, making sure to use a USA phone number which can receive SMS messages. You do _not_ need to enter the `+1` prefix, which would cause an issue if you were to do so.

Comment: Generate test user is failing now. POST https://jackhenry.dev/portal/api/users
, 500 Internal error; Request ID: 91532b2d6aa58885f62af4ec0a169f49

Comment: Thank you for the `x-request-id`. We'll work with Engineering to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Engineering has deployed a patch. Please try again, and if you get another failure please share the `x-request-id`.

Comment: @TylerWilson we've had success with someone else who tried this out, so we're hoping it'll also work for you.

Comment: I was able to generate a new test user but am still unable to enroll in Garden FI. I'm getting the same enrollment lookup error.

Comment: Can you share the request ID for the failing request? That'll make it easier for Engineering to debug.

Comment: 1850b806dacf74ce6205c7645d9a00ee

Comment: Thanks. We'll share with Engineering.

Comment: The strange thing is that we've seen _other_ developers successfully enroll test users since you've let us know about your issues. Hopefully trying again will sort things out (and please share the request ID of what's failing if possible). Also, carefully following the steps (which are a bit intricate) is helpful: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/accessing-the-digital-toolkit/

Comment: Still no success. When I load the enrollment page. I also see a 401 response to this URL. https://digital.garden-fi.com/a/consumer/api/enrollment/credentials/rules
 Request ID: 7c56d39f363c5ce874aeed35dda124a3. 400 response on https://digital.garden-fi.com/a/consumer/api/v0/enrollment/lookup
 Request ID: c1a40c78ec54ef9bc66eb8862bde6b01

Comment: Odd. We'll share with Engineering. Out of curiosity, do you have anything like content blockers or ad-blocker extensions in your browser? Curious what happens in an Incognito window, or if you clear your browser cache + cookies, or even try a different browser altogether.

Comment: From Engineering: *"Is there any way he can provide a sample json payload he’s sending to `/v0/enrollment/lookup`? He can _redact_ the sensitive information as long as the structure is the same (e.g. if he’s including dashes or any special characters)."*

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I tried from a guest window in Chrome and enrollment worked. The requests look the same. I use Edge normally and the only extensions I have are LastPass and React Dev Tools. The payload is too long to paste here.